# При выбранном чекбоксе делаем кнопку активной

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#agree').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            $('#add input[name="resume_add"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        else
            $('#add input[name="resume_add"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
</script>

<input id="agree" type="checkbox" value="1" name="agree">Я согласен на предоставление информации
<input id="add" type="submit" name="resume_add" value="Отправить" disabled>
```

Так оно почему-то не работает. Но не знаю почему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resume_add` по логике скрипта должно находиться внутри элемента с `id==add`. А у вас - это один и тот же элемент. Зачем к нему ТАК сложно обращаться, если у него есть вполне себе уникальный `id`?

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            $('#add').removeAttr('disabled');
        else
            $('#add').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Так должно работать.